# Where does Jenkins junit plugin store its data?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I'm using the jenkins test-results-analyzer plugin, which uses the jenkins Junit plugin.  They get the test results from the jenkins archive and import them into the plugins.  I then delete the archived test results, and the test results are still visible through the test-results-analyzer plugin.  This suggests that the test-results-analyzer/junit plugins must be storing the test results somewhere....but where?

I've run "du -h" in the jenkins script console and have looked at the directories containing both plugins but nothing jumps out as storing the test results, either in terms of naming convention or directory size...